# Get Hibernate to bind parameter type "char(1)" instead of "nvarchar(4000)"?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jdbc

DB side: SQL Server 2012. A data column is char(1) datatype.

ORM: Hibernate

Intention: Hibernate Query can bind a parameter properly, so no implicit datatype conversion in the query.

```
//not working as I intend. DB side still sees nvarchar(4000) 
Query.setCharacter("paramName", myChar)

Query.setParameter("paramName", myChar, Hibernate.Type.CHARACTER)

Query.setString("paramName", myCharStr)
```

None of above variation works. SQL server profiler indicates that the bound parameter type is navarchar(4000). SQL server ends up doing some implicit datatype conversion when running the query, and it messed up some of my initial intention. ([Rare and elusive deadlocks (select for update; then update) in case of multiple concurrent transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489457/rare-and-elusive-deadlocks-select-for-update-then-update-in-case-of-multiple))

Also it came to my attention that JDBC PreparedStatement API does not even have "setCharacter()". Not sure if this means anything. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html )

Is there a way to achieve the intention to bind a fixed length char, not nvarchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is not a Hibernate issue. Rather it is that collation set on this particular db column is different than DB collation. Once collation on this data column is fixed, then any of above  Hibernate method variation can bind proper parameter type. In case anyone else runs into similar issue.

Edit: another important setting is "**sendStringParametersAsUnicode**". SQL server JDBC driver by default sent character as "nvarchar" or "nchar", unless you append "sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false" in your connection string;

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2010/04/05/character-data-type-conversion-when-using-sql-server-jdbc-drivers.aspx

Comment: Here is a more targeted blog post on this issue: http://emransharif.blogspot.com/2011/07/performance-issues-with-jdbc-drivers.html